# Disable Friday and Saturday In Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to edit the beforeShowDay function in jquery.ui.datepicker.
This is the **original** beforeShowDay lines in datepicker I'm trying to replace:

```
beforeShowDay: null, // Function that takes a date and returns an array with
        // [0] = true if selectable, false if not, [1] = custom CSS class 
        name(s) or '',
        // [2] = cell title (optional), e.g. $.datepicker.noWeekends
```

I have searched around trying to find the correct code to replace it with with no luck.
I found this fiddle;
[disable 1 day in datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/nWAnz/140/)

I have edited this fiddle and succeeded in disabling Friday and Saturday with the following code:

```
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 1 || date.getDay() == 2 || date.getDay() == 3 || date.getDay() == 4 ] ;
    }
});
```

However when I copy and paste this into jquery.ui.datepicker the calendar does not function and I'm getting console errors (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token).

What I'm doing is replacing the **original** beforeShowDate with the following:

`beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            return [date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 1 || date.getDay() == 2 || date.getDay() == 3 || date.getDay() == 4 ] ;
        }`

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong and how I can get this to function correctly?

Comment: you don't need to copy paste anything into `jquery.ui.datepicker`. Always avoid modifying the jQuery plugins downloaded from third party sites. Above code should go into your own html page.

Comment: Hi vijayP, I tried to place this code into the html of the form but the form does not load now:
`<script type="text/javascript>$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            return [date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 1 || date.getDay() == 2 || date.getDay() == 3 || date.getDay() == 4 ] ;
        }
    });</script>`
I disagree about not editing the jquery.ui.datepicker for beforeShowDay because it has been commented out with vague clues about editing, meaning there is a way to edit this and that is what I am trying to find out how to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You should not edit the jQuery UI plugin directly**

If you really want then you have to paste this code replacing null. but it is **not recommended**.

```
function(date) {
    var show = true;
    if(date.getDay()==6||date.getDay()==0) show=false;
    return [show];
},//don't forget comma after the function
```

Right way to do is to pass the function while configuring the jquery ui date-picker inside your own js file.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
       var show = true;
       if(date.getDay()==6||date.getDay()==0) show=false
       return [show];
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly in jquery.ui.datepicker:
`beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var show = true;
    if(date.getDay()==5||date.getDay()==6) show=false
    return [show];
},`

Comment: Just to be clear, I c&p the first code supplied by Nadir Laskar straight into the beforeShowDate element in jquery.ui.datepicker and it worked correctly. I've spent 2 days trying to find a solution for this and trying dozens of snippets from various fiddles, pens and stackoverflow but this is the first one that has actually worked :-) fyi.... i just make one change; from 0 & 6 to 5 & 6

Comment: Nice and simple solution. Worked just like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

> **[daysOfWeekDisabled](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#daysofweekdisabled)**
>
> Days of the week that should be disabled. Values are 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday). Multiple values should be comma-separated. Example: disable weekends: '06' or '0,6' or [0,6].

Use `daysOfWeekDisabled` for this

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [5,6]
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/1021/)

**Edit**

I did mistake in reading and post above answer about bootstarp datepicker.

For Jquery UI Datepicker try this

```
beforeShowDay: function(d) {
   return [!(d.getDay()==0||d.getDay()==6)]
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fg6uc225/2/)

Comment: I tried that but the calendar does not load (even after clear the cache and refresh), this is what I did:
I replaced this:

`beforeShowDay: null, // Function that takes a date and returns an array with
   // [0] = true if selectable, false if not, [1] = custom CSS class name(s) or '',
   // [2] = cell title (optional), e.g. $.datepicker.noWeekends`

With this:

`beforeShowDay: $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});`

Maybe my implementation is incorrect?

Comment: @MichaelJoseph Implementation will be same as I did in my example

Comment: You read the question wrong its about jquery UI datepicker not bootstrap datepicker

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 5 && day != 6), ''];
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nWAnz/238/

Comment: Hi Trimantra, that is for Saturday and Sunday whereas I want to disable Friday and Saturday